# Preventing box2d player from pressing against walls in midair

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, box2d, physics

I have setup a box2d world with a keyboard controlled player. The player can walk and jump. How do I prevent the player from "sticking" to walls while jumping and pressing the directional key towards an object?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make player body as group of bodies (add fixtures at left and right sides)? and set friction to 0
[image]

Comment: Interesting approach. I will try it. I have also been thinking of setting the friction of the body to zero and adding a feet fixture with friction. What are the pros and cons of that?

Comment: sure, you can set body fixture friction to zero and have feet fixture with non zero friction, but, if your feet and body fixtures will have same width, you will have same effect (sticking) when feet will touch the wall. if you will set feet width less then bodys width, you could have troubles with corners.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the way that you're affecting the body of the character. What method are you using to move him left/right? Try applyLinearImpulse on the body and also ensure that your friction in the body definition isn't really high.

Comment: I am applying linear velocity. If I set the friction to 0 I get the result I want, but I have to use another friction on ground. Otherwise the player will be iceskating.

Comment: What is your friction set at by default?

Comment: The default value is set to 1.

Comment: 1 is max friction the value has to be between 1.0 (100%) and 0(0%) so set it something moderate between 0 and 1.

Comment: if you set friction to 0 you will have trouble with inclined platforms

Answer (score 1):

You can set the friction of your player to 0 and then execute in every loop a function that set your velocity in X to zero when user is not pressing the movement keys. In your method to check events you should add:

```
if (event.type == KeyReleased) {
    if (!isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left) && !isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) {
        player.stop();
     }
}
```

And in your player.stop() you should do something like:

```
b2Vec2 vel = body->GetLinearVelocity();
vel.x = 0;
body->SetLinearVelocity(vel);
```

This will make your player has friction 0 with platforms with the iceskating

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your physics is currently working, as there are a lot of possibilities. The simplest way to do it in my opinion, is to split the shown body into 4 boundary walls (top, left, right, bottom) and only have the walk-able floor (top) produce friction.

Comment: So you are proposing that every platform should have four sides? Or are you talking about the player?

Comment: Either, depends on your purposes, how you're currently coding things and what else you have in your application (boxes to push and whatnot).